# "This video is unavailable" when putting music videos in iFrame

Tags: youtube-data-api

So I developed an app that fetches the youtube video for songs. 2 months ago this worked without fail. Came back to my app and suddenly getting the static-y error "This video is unavailable".

Double checked that the video on Youtube is actually there and plays, and I also checked to see if the uploader allows embedding by using https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=l-EdCNjumvI&key=[MYKEY]&part=snippet,contentDetails,status

I got the status response as follows:
"status" : {
     "embeddebable" : true
}

So I know I should be able to embed that particular video. 
Any advice?

I am able to put other non-music videos into the iframe without fail.

Works: 
    `<iframe width="560" height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PUvWR0HdQmg" frameborder="0" 
    allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Doesn't work: 
    `<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l- 
    EdCNjumvI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>`

Edit: it seems music videos need a server to be running in order to play. I don't know why this is, but I started a simple http server using 
`python -m http.server 80` 
and for some reason that is above my expertise, that worked

Comment: Your video links under "Works" and "Doesn't work" aren't showing up for me.

Comment: Hmm weird, I posted the iframes for the video. Ok i think I got it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After testing your two pieces of code, it seems that the spaces in the second example may be the problem.

Instead of

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l- 
EdCNjumvI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen> 
</iframe>
```

consider using

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l-EdCNjumvI" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen> 
</iframe>
```

where there are no spaces after the hyphen.

This may be due to the fact that the spaces in your example are WITHIN the src string, meaning that in your original example, the src string was

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l-     EdCNjumvI"`

rather than

`src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/l-EdCNjumvI"`

Comment: Hmm, I copied your example and I still get that error. I can see the thumbnail, just hitting play causes the "The video is unavailable"

Comment: Hmm. I went and copied the embed code straight from YouTube and it failed. I tested some examples with - and they worked, so I'm going to have to assume that it's an issue with YouTube. Maybe the video's settings don't allow it to be embedded, or there's some kind of other restriction?

Comment: I found a fix actually. For some reason, music videos need a web server in order to play. So I just did a simple http server by using python - m http.server 80 and it worked. I don't know why it would need that, so if anybody could explain that would be great

Comment: Is that some kind of Youtube-specific thing for music videos?